# Submit Parent Page after closing Modal Dialog in ORACLE APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using an interactive report in Oracle Apex with rows and columns to display and edit some data in a tabular form. I have an icon, which on clicking, opens a Modal Dialog Page, where some data is entered.

Now on closing the dialog page ( the *action* is *submit page* on the *close* button of the dialog ), the parent page behind is just getting **re-rendered** and I am losing all the edited data entered before opening the modal dialog.

I am not able to find a way that would also **Submit** Parent Page after closing Modal Dialog so that all the values entered before opening dialog also get saved when the parent page gets submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you have a tabular form on the parent page.
In this report you have a link that opens a modal. in this modal you fill some data.
You need to click a button, save the data you filled in the modal, and submit the parent page.

If so, try doing this:

1 - In the modal create a dynamic action to execute a code pl/sql and save your data in the modal page by clicking on a button.

2 - In this same dynamic action create another true action to close the modal "Close Dialog".

3 - On the parent page create a dynamic action where:

Event: Dialog closed

Selection Type: Region

Region: the region of the report

Condition: No condition

True Action: submit the page to save the form tabular

[image]

Comment: I understood your solution. But here there is an issue that i am facing. 

I have some data in the modal page being entered in some fields and stored in their respective application items. Now those application items DO NOT save the value of the fields unless there is a submit action on a Button. And on Submit, the modal page closes with the parent page just being re-rendered and not submitting and hence lose all my old data. I hope you got what i am trying to say.

Comment: You can save modal page data in dynamic action, you just need to declare the items to be submitted. see the image from the above post.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Had to modify a few things in my code to make this work.